# for loop: Nested array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested, splice

My code:

```
let newArr = [[1,5,6,4],[8,5,4],[4,4,4,4]];

function filterArr(arr, elemn){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        if(arr[i][j] === elemn){
        arr[i].splice(j,1);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(filterArr(newArr,4));
```

The Result:
[[1,5,6],[8,5],[4,4]]

I am stuck at this point :
[4,4] it supposed []

any suggestion plz ...

Comment: You’re mutating an array as you iterate it, but never adjust the index. Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll quote some sentences from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

> ***deleteCount*** *Optional* 
> An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start.
>
> If *deleteCount* is omitted, or if its value is equal to or larger than array.length - start (that is, if it is equal to or greater than the number of elements left in the array, starting at start), then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted.
>
> If *deleteCount* is 0 or negative, no elements are removed. In this case, you should specify at least one new element (see below).

You delete `j`th element and `j++` so that the next of deleted element is skipped after deletion. After once deletion you should use `j--`.

The full right code is as follows:

```js
let newArr = [[1,5,6,4],[8,5,4],[4,4,4,4]];

function filterArr(arr, elemn){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
        if(arr[i][j] === elemn){
        arr[i].splice(j, 1);
        j --;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(filterArr(newArr,4));
```

Comment: before adding j-- there was a problem..now it is ok

Comment: @AbdulhameedSabur, yup, the first time i wrote, i didn't have read your question more deeply

Comment: You are awesome

Answer (score 1):

Global newArray.

```
let newArr = [[1,5,6,4],[8,5,4],[4,4,4,4]];
```

Here is filterArr function, parameter is same.

```
let result = [];
for (let item of newArr){
    for (let i = 0; i< item.length; i++){
        if (item[i] == elemn){
            item.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
     result.push(item);
}

return result;
```

You can call filterArr function and show same result as you expect.

```
console.log(filterArr(newArr,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

As metioned in the comments, you might check out the [javascript `Array` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).  There is a built in `filter` method which might simplify this a bit.

```
let newArr = [[1,5,6,4],[8,5,4],[4,4,4,4]];

function filterArray(arr, valueToFilter) {
   return arr.map( (subArray) => subArray.filter( (value) => value !== valueToFilter ) );
}

console.log(filterArray(newArr,4));
```

Comment: You are right.. But I want it with for loop 